# ActiveX Control is running in separate window other than IE

Tags: c#, winforms, internet-explorer, activex, com-interop

I have developed an ActiveX Control in C#.NET. I created a class library with a default interface. Given GUID , ProgId and made it COM visible , interoperable. Registered. Created a cab file , then embedded it in HTML page using object tag by specifying it's classid and codebase. Loaded it using JavaScript Method. It is working. But problem is that it runs as a separate window other than Internet explorer. I want it to be loaded inside IE that is as a part of IE window. How to do it?

--
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably, you show your control in a separate `Form`. You'd just need to derive your control from `UserControl`, register it and let the ActiveX container (IE in your case) embed your control in-place. Check out [C# ActiveX control (CSActiveX)](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsdesktop/CSActiveX-c3f43e7d) and [Interop Forms Toolkit for C#](http://interoptoolkitcs.codeplex.com/).

Comment: Thanks for this answer and useful links.