# How to use a Control created in C# as a form in VB6

Tags: c#, vb6, com-interop

I have a user control created in a C# solution and I have to use that control in an existing form in VB. I am new to vb. Please help me out in this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Check this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/375457/cant-instantiate-a-com-object-written-in-c-sharp-from-vba-vb6-ok)

Comment: Are you sure? you want to use .net dll in VB? That won't work if .net is not installed?

Comment: yes. Dotnet is already installed.I am trying to use it like this.

Set mctldemo = Controls.Add("Democtl.Control", "ctlDemo", Me)

Comment: I feel sorry for you having to still work with VB6.

Comment: A related answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19092026/1768303

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have set the control like this when loading the data:

```
   Set mctldemo = Controls.Add("Democtl.Control", "ctlDemo", Me)
```

But forgot to mention the ClassInterface as shown in this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/375457/cant-instantiate-a-com-object-written-in-c-sharp-from-vba-vb6-ok)

```
[ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.AutoDual)]
    [ProgId("Democtl.Control")]
```

Thank you all for responding to my question and thank you Nadeem_MK for the link

Answer (score -1):

It seems this is not supported. I've never tried - why would I - but others have:

- http://bytes.com/topic/net/answers/120973-ole-net-control-office
- http://support.microsoft.com/kb/839076

However according to support documents, it may be just barely possible to make it work by hosting the dotNet usercontrol within a WebBrowser instance on the VB6 control.

- http://support.microsoft.com/kb/317346

But I really suggest you don't do that. I can't help thinking it would be easier to upgrade the whole form to dotNet... indeed the whole project to VB.Net...

Alternatively you could rewrite the usercontrol as a VB6 usercontrol.

Comment: Aren't your three links are for different problems? (i) displaying a .Net control in an Office document (ii) displaying a .Net form from VB6 (iii) displaying a .Net control from Internet Explorer. The question is about displaying a .Net control (not form) in a VB6 form. BTW upgrading VB6->VB.Net [can be a massive undertaking](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vb6-migration).